# deploy zend framework online

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to php zend framework, I think I can get zend worked in my local computer but I am not sure how to deploy zend on line. if I have a web sever and filezilla ftp transfer tool, what I need to do to be able to get zend work online like i did locally? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to deploy and tell us if there is any problem

Comment: You connect to the server and upload it in the web root directory (public_html, www, http...). If you used a db, remember to export/import that too (with phpmyadmin or similar tools)

Comment: so you mean just do the same as I upload normal php file right?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of Zend Framework is that it is very non-intrusive by nature. It is more a class set than a framework but you can use the MVC framework too to build awesome apps. My knowledge of the Zend Framework is that you simply have to upload your source on the server like it was in your original site on your machine.

If you are using a non-conventionnal way to detect or set the path of the autoloader then you MIGHT have issues to fix. But if you use the define(APPLICATION_PATH, realpath(dirname(**FILE**)) strategy and set the includepath correctly, there should be no problem at all.